# How to get a cmake subdirectory to inherit the toolchain

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to learn cmake and do some basic stuff.  It's not going well.

This output seems completely bizarre and broken:

```
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 10.2.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe - works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done 
         PLATFORM_DIR: /home/dtrombley/src/p0/platform/x86_64-pc-cygwin Building on x86_64-pc-cygwin 
     Including contrib-src/glad... 
     CMake Error at contrib-src/glad/CMakeLists.txt:19 (project):   The CMAKE_C_COMPILER:
 
    x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
    is not a full path and was not found in the PATH.
    Tell CMake where to find the compiler by setting either the environment   variable "CC" or the CMake cache entry CMAKE_C_COMPILER to the full path to   the compiler, or to the compiler name if it is in the PATH.
   
-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! See also "/home/dtrombley/src/p0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log". See also "/home/&lt;user&gt;/src/p0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

I have a CMakeLists.txt in the top directory of my project, that finds my compiler just fine - as you can see about.  The compiler is on the system path:

```
$ which x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
/usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc
```

Then I include a subdirectory with `add_subdirectory()`, and it complains that it can't find the C compiler.  Which the parent project has found.   Shouldn't CMAKE_C_COMPILER be set and inherited by the child directory?

Why would the parent directory be able to find it, but the child directory cannot?

Additionally, setting the CC environment variable as suggested has zero effect.

What is going on here?  Setting CMAKE_C_COMPILER explicitly results in the same output.

Comment: What you are doing is definitely NOT a "basic stuff" as you name it. The message `Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc.exe - works` means that CMake has discovered a compiler and checked it. But the message like `is not a full path and was not found in the PATH` means that CMake tries to discover/check a compiler **again**, which shouldn't occurred normally.  It **smells** like your project runs configuration of another project via `execute_process`. In any case we cannot help you without viewing **more code** of your project.

Comment: My project has no code, I'm just setting it up.  It literally cannot get more "basic", I don't even have any source files in my project, just two dependencies.  The CMakeLists.txt consists of just a `project()` decl and two `add_subdirectory()` which contain two upstream release projects that use cmake as a build system and both build fine from the command line.  https://pastebin.com/1bKvbjy9  How is this not "basic"?  There is absolutely no execute_process call to another cmake build, as you can see.

Comment: When you include other project using `add_subdirectory` it becomes **part of your code**: Most projects are expected to be built standalone (as top-level projects), so once you use a project in unexpected way, no one guarantees that the project will work correctly. BTW, have you tried to build the `glad` project **standalone**, using the same settings?

Comment: I understand that. I knew I was making it part of my code base when I copied it into my source tree.  GLFW expects your project to be built exactly in this way, I'm just following their docs.  See https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3.2/build.html.  In any case, this isn't a question about how to get glfw to work.  It's a question about why the compiler is obviously found (lines 2 and 3 in the input), and then somehow "unfound" when configuring a subdirectory CMakeLists.txt.  (And if this is a bug/reportable, or somehow "expected", or I need some line/option that isn't currently present...)

Comment: If you suspect that `glad` project is unrelated to your problem then try to reproduce the problem **without** it, having only the `project()` call in the subdirectory. This debug approach is known as [mcve], and it is very effective when you seek a help for your problem.

Comment: If `PLATFORM_DIR` variable is not related to your problem, then try to reproduce the problem without it. But if this variable is crucial for your **toolchain**, then show that toolchain (add it to the question post). Actually, it smells like the toolchain you use incorrectly sets some variables, so CMake tries to search for the compiler twice.

Comment: PLATFORM_DIR is just a variable I set to help me debug, nothing ever references it (unless it's accidentally a cmake builting, but it doesn't appear in the docs).  Anyway same result w/o it.

Comment: Please, update your question post with [mcve]: the **exact code**  and the **exact output** it causes.

Comment: The cmake lists file is already given above.  Just unpack glad (https://github.com/Dav1dde/glad into the glad subdir, and glfw (https://www.glfw.org/) into the 'glfw' subdir. There's nothing else.  The "exact output" is obviously also in the question.